# calculate pixel coordinates for 8 equidistant points on a circle

Tags: python-2.7, math, trigonometry

I have a circle centred at 0 with radius 80. How using python do I calculate the coordinates for 8 equidistant points around the circumference of the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = 80
numPoints = 8.0
points = []
for index in range(numPoints):
    points.append([r*math.cos((index*2*math.pi)/numPoints),r*math.sin((index*2*math.pi)/numPoints)])
return points
```

you can simplify this some if you know you are always going to have only 8 points with something like:

```
r = 80
numPoints = 8
points = []
x = (r*math.sqrt(2))/2
points = [[0,r],[x,x],[r,0],[-x,x],[-r,0],[-x,-x],[0,-r],[x,-x]]
print points
```

with x being the x/y of the point 45 degrees and 80 units away from the origin

Answer (score 1):

[click this pic for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LtV0.jpg)

in the above  picture.

coordinates 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 are equidistant points on a circumference of circle Radius R and its centre is at X (0,0)

take the triangle XLZ , its aright angled at L ,

Let     LZ = H ,
    LY = A

```
    XL + LY = R => XL + A = R => XL = R-A
```

since XLZ is right angled ,  XZ square = XL square + LZ square

```
                R square = (R-A) square + h square ————1
```

since these 8 points makes an octagon  theta = 360 deg / 8 =  45 deg

tan 45 deg = h / XL = h / R-A => 1 = h/ R-A => h = R-A —————2

Z coordinates are (R-A, h) = > (h,h)

from the equations 1 and 2

R square = h square + h square => 2 h square = R square =>  h = R/ sqrt 2

so the coordinates  at point 2 (Z) = (R/sqrt2, R/sqrt2)

remaining can be derived easily as they are just oppside

So all coordinates  are

1   (0,R)
2   (R/sqrt2,R/sqrt2)
3    (R,0)
4   (-R/sqrt2, R/sqrt2)
5    (-R,0)
6   (-R/sqrt2,-R/sqrt2)
7    (0,-R)
8   (R/sqrt2, -R/sqrt2)